# Hover effect on IOS / Mobile devices, I have tied :active :hover and :focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am currently making my website responsive and mobile friendly, my site uses :hover a lot in desktop browsers to allow the user to get more information and for general site effects.

One of the places I use hover on is on the product specification pages:

http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/268/Canon_EOS_200D

Please click and hold on one of the specification items in your desktop browser, it should look like this:

[image]

I want to remake this effect on mobile devices, I have tried using :active and :focus and both of these either do the trick.

Another issue is the search bar, in desktop browsers the search bar shows and disappears on mouse hover in CSS

[image]

Please try the search bar in a mobile browser : http://cameras.specced.co.uk

When you click the search icon in the top right the hover effect activates and shows the search bar however does not disappear when you press anywhere else on the display.

I have not posted the CSS code here because it is extremely simple with just display:none and on :hover of the icon it goes display:block.... I have tried both active and focus and read many other stack overflow posts about this however can't get it to work.

It would be appreciated if you tested this on your mobile device to see the effect I mention. Thankyou

Comment: There's no hover on mobile devices. When you touch your screen it's a click. Maybe that 3d touch thing has hover but generally smartphones don't have such thing as hover.

Comment: There must be a way to display on hold ?

Comment: You have the function touchstart and touchend if you want to run events on hold. You do it like `$(".content").bind("touchstart",function(){ //something happens when hold })`